# How to add WPF treeView Node Click event to get the node value

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a `TreeView` in wpf how can one get the `TreeView` node click event so that I can get the value of the node on which the user has clicked?

#### Xaml

```
<Grid Height="258" Width="275">
    <TreeView Height="258" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275">    
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

I have populated this `TreeView` from the C# code. What event methode do I need to write into c# code to get the value of clicked node by the user in my c# code.

#### Code Behind to Load

```
TreeViewItem treeItem = null;
treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
treeItem.Header = "Name";
```

Comment: where is the c# code? you need clicked node or selected node? usually after click a node gets selected too.

Comment: @pushpraj Actually sir the C# code is long .So i have posted only small snippet that i have added into Window_loaded of the app

Comment: @Ok Sir.I need the Clicked One sir..

Comment: @pushpraj Sir string header=item.Header; Is it Correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there is no Click event available for TreeViewItem  or TreeView so here are possible workaround for the same

you have two options from C# code

using `MouseLeftButtonUp` which will trigger every time the mouse left button is released on the item, which is similar to click

```
    void preparemethod()
    {
        ...
        TreeViewItem treeItem = null;
        treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
        treeItem.Header = "Name";
        treeItem.MouseLeftButtonUp += treeItem_MouseLeftButtonUp;
    }

    void treeItem_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //your logic here
    }
```

or use Selected as trigger, may not trigger if a selected element is clicked

```
    void preparemethod()
    {
        ...
        TreeViewItem treeItem = null;
        treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
        treeItem.Header = "Name";
        treeItem.Selected += treeItem_Selected;
    }

    void treeItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //your logic here
    }
```

in both of the approach the sender is the node which has been clicked. you can use as

example

```
    void treeItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = sender as TreeViewItem;
        //you can access item properties eg item.Header etc. 
        //your logic here 
    }
```

Comment: Ok Sir .As i am first time working on wpf So how to get the selected value from the sender into string

Comment: you can access item properties eg item.Header etc. after casting sender to TreeViewItem, see updated answer.

Comment: OK Sir .What property i need to call if i have to access the other value of the node except the header

Comment: string header=item.Header;  Is it Correct?

Comment: `string header = item.Header as string;` would work as `Header` property is of type `object`.

Comment: Ok Sir One Doubt sir if i want to get the items that has been clicked how can i get that .As of now i am getting Header name only while clicking items of treeView

Comment: if I am not wrong the item in `TreeViewItem item = sender as TreeViewItem;` is the TreeViewItem  which is been selected. if not then please clarify what do you mean by item?

Comment: `TreeViewItem item = sender as TreeViewItem;` This is giving some different event generated values.and When i am writing this  `string header = item.Header as string;` it is giving header of the tree .Instead of this i want to get the node value which has been clicked.How to get it

Comment: I am bit lost here, item is the node which is clicked, item.Header is the text what you see in the node text and item.Items is it's child items. if the value is none of them then what else is the value which you are interested in? where do you set that value?

Comment: OK Sir Got the answer.One more query sir how to access items because this  `string itemName = item.Items as string;` is giving error .Thank YOu.

Comment: item.Items is a collection of objects the sub items so you can use as TreeViewItem child1 = item.Items[0] as TreeViewItem; or you can access in a foreach loop on item.Items. foreach(TreeViewItem child in item.Items) { //your logic here}

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir!Now i have another issue  where i have nodes inside node.Now for this what i should do to get the items of those node.

Comment: perhaps you could post a new question describing your problem with details to reproduce the same. as this discussion is already too long and there is a notice `Please avoid extended discussions in comments.` so let's not extend it further.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885241/getting-the-value-of-the-child-nodes-on-click-event-in-wpf-treeview Please see my new Post Sir

Comment: Please see my link sir .Any suggestion would be life saving.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to take a more MVVM friendly approach you can use an interaction trigger on your TreeView ItemTemplate and bind the command with a parameter of the treeview item object back to your parent ViewModel:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, Mode=OneWay}" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTreeViewItemClickedCommand,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=trvMainMenu,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

If one has added a context menu to a treeview, the onclick event only returns the menu item it was clicked on, its the visual tree.

A better way to get the actual treeview item is to do these steps

1. Name the `TreeView` which the operation in question is occurring such as `tView` for this example.
2. In the click event of the menu (or any other event actually) get the current selected item `var node = tView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem`

If there is no currently selected item, tell the user to select the item and do the process again. Once selected, at that point you have the actual tree view item to work with and do what is needed.

---

```
<TreeView x:Name="tView"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Click="CopyChildrenToClipboard"
                      Header="Copy Children To Clipboard">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="assets/check_green.png"
                           Height="16" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TreeView.ContextMenu>
</TreeView>
```