# WPF C# TreeView get text of selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, treeview

I've got the following TreeView:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView" 
                  MouseDoubleClick="TreeView_MouseDoubleClick"
                  Width="350">
            <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="CogOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Configuration" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="TruckDeliveryOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Items"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowUpBoldBoxOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Configuration"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="FileDocumentOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="List"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ClipboardMultipleOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Management"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ClipboardListOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Management"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ClipboardPlusOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Sundry Items"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="RelationOneToMany" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Sundry Addition"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ClipboardPlusOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Sundry Addition"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="RelationOneToMany" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Addition Relations"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="FormatListBulleted" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Tasks" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="TruckDeliveryOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Items"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ChartFinance" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="(Converted)"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ChartFinance" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="(Each)"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="CurrencyGbp" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Material"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="CurrencyGbp" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Product"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Check" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Validation"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Update" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Update All"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Salesforce" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Bundle"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Calculator" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Calculator"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="HelpCircleOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Help" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="BookOpenOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Guide"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Link" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Link"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                </TreeViewItem>
            
        </TreeView>
```

It is to be used as navigation in a menu form, but I am struggling to create an event which would trigger when something is clicked and then return the text value that is displayed on the item in the tree view.

I've tried the following articles:

[Getting the value of the Selected Child Nodes on click Event in WPF TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885241/getting-the-value-of-the-selected-child-nodes-on-click-event-in-wpf-treeview)

[How to add WPF treeView Node Click event to get the node value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880824/how-to-add-wpf-treeview-node-click-event-to-get-the-node-value)

Using solutions from both, don't work for me as I am not able to access the `item.header` in one and in other cases it doesn't seem to correctly create the `TreeViewItem item = sender as  TreeViewItem`.

Have I over-complicated my hard-coded `TreeView` to a point where I am unable to create such event to return me the text value of the clicked item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify Tag property for each TreeViewItem.
In MouseClick event handler -> you will able to convert sender to TreeViewItem.. and
then you will be able to take Tag property of it

```
<TreeViewItem Tag="Link" MouseLeftButtonDown="ClickItem_Handler">
 ...
</TreeViewItem>
```

in codebehind of your form

```
protected void ClickItem_Handler(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    if (sender is TreeViewItem item){
        var header = item.Tag as string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Just instead of the `OnClick` I used `MouseDoubleClick` event.