# C# WPF TreeViewItem MouseDoubleClick event on TreeViewItem with TreeViewItem.Header

Tags: c#, wpf, events, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a `TreeView` which contains mixture of different levels of `TreeViewItem`'s.

Below works perfectly:

```
            <TreeViewItem Tag="Link" MouseDoubleClick="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Link" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Link"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
```

But when it comes to ones where they have a `TreeViewItem.Header` I'm not able to set the `MouseDoubleClick` event correctly, see below:

```
            <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True" MouseDoubleClick="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="HelpCircleOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Help" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
                <ContentControl>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="BookOpenOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Technical Guide"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ContentControl>
            </TreeViewItem>
```

Issue with the above is that it triggers on both the Help header and the Technical Guide child.

I cannot add the event onto the `<StackPanel>` as it doesn't support it, so I wrapped it with `<ContentControl>` and tried adding the event to that, but it doesn't seem to trigger at all.

Is there any way of only having the "Technical Guide" triggering the event, but also adding in the `Tag=""` property as per the first code snippet as I am checking for that value in the `TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick` event?

EDIT

As requested providing code for the `MouseDoubleClick` event:

```
    private void TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TreeViewItem item)
        {
            var header = item.Tag as string;
            switch (header)
            {
                case "Link":
                       //Open new window code
                    break;
             }
     }
```

Comment: could you show your code of event doubleclick? or better have you a place where i could download your project?

Comment: @Frenchy see edited question :)

Comment: i need to see your complete xaml file to reproduce the problem you have,

Comment: @Frenchy The page consists just of the `TreeView`and the XAML for that can be found on this question from earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69898323/wpf-c-sharp-treeview-get-text-of-selected-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot add the event onto the `<StackPanel>` as it doesn't support it ...

Yes, you if you set the `Background` property to `Transparent` and handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event and check the `ClickCount` property of the `MouseButtonEventArgs`:

```
private void StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        //double-click detected
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
            Background="Transparent"
            MouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <TextBlock Text="Technical Guide"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of trapping click from treeview, why you dont trap click from textblock?

```
        <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True"   >
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="HelpCircleOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Help" FontWeight="Bold" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="BookOpenOutline" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Technical Guide" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem>
```

---

```
    private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // simulate doubleclick
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((TextBlock)sender.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That works, although only when the click is done exactly on the text, meaning if clicking on the TreeViewItem, but not the text, nothing happens. It is not that big of a deal, but I thought that it may be possible in some way to achieve it with the click TreeViewItem.

Comment: in anyways its not the best way to build a treeview  see https://wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/   this is the way to build a treview with binding.